# Rolling window on timestamped DataFrame with a custom step?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, windowing

I have been fiddling about with [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for some time now and I haven't been able to achieve the result that I am looking for, so before I write a custom windowing function I figured I would ask if I'm missing something.

I have postgresql data with a composite index of `(time, node)` that has been read into a `pandas.DataFrame`, where `time` is a certain hour on a certain date. I need to create windows that contain all entries within the last two calendar dates (or any arbitrary number of days), for example, beginning at `2022-12-26 00:00:00` and ending on `2022-12-27 23:00:00`, and then perform operations on that window to return a new, resultant DataFrame. The window should then move forward **an entire calendar date**, which is where I am failing.

```
| time                  | node  | value  |
| --------------------- | ----- | ------ |
| 2022-12-26 00:00:00   | 123   | low    |
| 2022-12-26 01:00:00   | 123   | med    |
| 2022-12-26 02:00:00   | 123   | low    |
| 2022-12-26 03:00:00   | 123   | high   |
| ...                   | ...   | ...    |
| 2022-12-26 00:00:00   | 999   | low    |
| 2022-12-26 01:00:00   | 999   | low    |
| 2022-12-26 02:00:00   | 999   | low    |
| 2022-12-26 03:00:00   | 999   | med    |
| ...                   | ...   | ...    |
| 2022-12-27 00:00:00   | 123   | low    |
| 2022-12-27 01:00:00   | 123   | med    |
| 2022-12-27 02:00:00   | 123   | low    |
| 2022-12-27 03:00:00   | 123   | high   |
```

When I use something akin to `df.rolling(window=pd.Timedelta('2days')`, the windows move forward hour-by-hour, as opposed to beginning on the next calendar date.

I've played around with using `min_periods`, but it doesn't seem to work with my data, nor would it be acceptable in the long run because the number of expected observations per window is not fixed regardless. The `step` parameter also appears to be useless in this case because I am using an offset versus an integer for the window anyways.

Is the behaviour I am looking for doable with [`pandas.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) or must I look elsewhere/write my own windowing function?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what you mean by any arbitrary number of days , you need to fix it some i.e. 2 days , 3 days or 10 days,

Comment: This might be too inefficient, but you could consider doing a normal rolling apply, and then take your output from the result at offsets of a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I understand, you want to create windows of length `ndays` and the next window should start with the next day.

Given some dataframe with 5 days in total in the frequency of 1H between indices:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

periods = 23 * 5
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'value': list(range(periods))},
    index=pd.date_range('2022-12-16', periods=periods, freq='H')
)
d = np.random.choice(
    pd.date_range('2022-12-16', periods=periods, freq='H'),
    int(periods * 0.25)
)
df = df.drop(index=d)
df.head(5)          
>>>                  value
2022-12-16 00:00:00      0
2022-12-16 01:00:00      1
2022-12-16 02:00:00      2
2022-12-16 04:00:00      4
2022-12-16 05:00:00      5
```

I randomly dropped some indices to simulate missing data.
We can use `df.resample` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)) to group the data by days (regardless of missing data):

```py
days = df.resample('1d')
print(days.get_group('2022-12-16'))
>>>                  value
2022-12-16 00:00:00      0
2022-12-16 01:00:00      1
2022-12-16 02:00:00      2
2022-12-16 04:00:00      4
2022-12-16 05:00:00      5
2022-12-16 06:00:00      6
2022-12-16 07:00:00      7
2022-12-16 08:00:00      8
2022-12-16 09:00:00      9
2022-12-16 11:00:00     11
2022-12-16 12:00:00     12
2022-12-16 13:00:00     13
2022-12-16 14:00:00     14
2022-12-16 15:00:00     15
2022-12-16 17:00:00     17
2022-12-16 18:00:00     18
2022-12-16 19:00:00     19
2022-12-16 21:00:00     21
2022-12-16 22:00:00     22
2022-12-16 23:00:00     23
```

Now, we only need to iterate over the days in a "sliding" manner. The package [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) has some helpful functions, such as [windowed](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html) and we can easily control the size of the window (here with `ndays`):

```py
from more_itertools import windowed
ndays = 2
windows = [
    pd.concat([w[1] for w in window])
    for window in windowed(days, ndays)
]
```

Printing the first and last index of each window returns:

```py
for window in windows:
    print(window.iloc[[0, -1]])

>>>                  value
2022-12-16 00:00:00      0
2022-12-17 23:00:00     47
                     value
2022-12-17 00:00:00     24
2022-12-18 23:00:00     71
                     value
2022-12-18 00:00:00     48
2022-12-19 23:00:00     95
                     value
2022-12-19 01:00:00     73
2022-12-20 18:00:00    114
```

Furthermore, you can set `step` in `windowed` to control the step size between windows.